# expand/collapse sharepoint list group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I found multiple scripts that are relevant to the "expand/collapse" SharePoint list group; however, most are looking at the "minus/plus"sign to expand/collapse. the problem  is that, when I added a list view webpart to a webpart page, the group icon shows a "triangle" not a "minus/plus"sign, even when i changed the list style to "basic table". Please kindly let me know how I can fix this?

```
function collapseGroups() {
$("img[src*='minus.gif']:visible").parent().click();
}
function expandGroups() {
$("img[src*='plus.gif']:visible").parent().click();
}
```

[image: issue]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? - Also, if you F12 into the list view, you can work out what CSS is applied and what generates the triangles, no?

Comment: the issue is that when i added the list view webpart to a webpart page, the group icon shows a "triangle" not "minus/plus" sign, and the code is checking the "minus/plus" sign to expand/collapse the group. The code is working well if it is added to the list view webpart page directly(by changi n the list style to "basic table")

Comment: Again, can't you identify the underlying graphic for the triangle with F12 Developer Tools? If you can see it on your screen, you can inspect it with F12.

Comment: <img class="ms-commentexpand-icon" id="img_21-1_" alt="expand" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23">

Comment: Well, there you go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change default Expand collapse icon to plus minus icon, put script editor webpart on page and put following code into it, change js and image src accordingly.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/ABC/SiteAssets/js/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', 'img', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("ms-commentexpand-icon")){
        $(this).attr("src","/sites/ABC/SiteAssets/images/icons8-PLUS-50.png");
        $(".ms-commentexpand-icon").css({top: 0, left: 0});
    }else if($(this).hasClass("ms-commentcollapse-icon")){
        $(this).attr("src","/sites/ABC/SiteAssets/images/icons8-minus-50.png");
        $(".ms-commentcollapse-icon").css({top: 0, left: 0});
    }
});
});
$(window).on('load', function() {
$('.ms-commentexpand-icon').attr("src","/sites/ABC/SiteAssets/images/icons8-PLUS-50.png");
$('.ms-commentcollapse-icon').attr("src","/sites/ABC/SiteAssets/images/icons8-minus-50.png");
$(".ms-commentexpand-icon").css({top: 0, left: 0});
$(".ms-commentcollapse-icon").css({top: 0, left: 0});
});

</script>
```